# Change the screen when click on the button

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, navigation, screen

I am new to Blackberry..I am developing an application which contain the home screen having a button on it. When clicked on it, it is changing to new screen for that I used UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NewScreen()); in the fieldchangedListener method.
 In the newscreen I added a verticalFieldManager and add some images and a button.What I want is when I click on this button it should takes to the homescreen.

I implemented the second screen functionality in NewScreen class which is in the main class.

Please let me know any suggestions.

Thanks 
Koushik

Comment: What is the behavior you are seeing? Not sure what the question is.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123414/how-to-navigate-back-to-the-previous-screen-in-blackberry

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to go back to the previous screen.
try this.

```
Screen currentScreen = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen();
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(currentScreen);
```

Comment: Hi Vivart thanks for the suggestion..But I used this code snippet and see but it is not working for me. I dont know where I commetted mistake. 
Actually what I am doing is, I wrote the code for homescreen in a class with button and I implement the code for secondscreen(when displayed the button clicked on homescreen) with a btn whn clicked on it should takes to the homescreen adding in a VFM in another class which is in same class.
So I implemented the Fieldchangelisterner and put the setChangelisters in corresponding classes.
Can you please explain me where I committed the mistake.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write this a code snippet, then I can help you.
Perhaps You need to overload methods onClose, onSave or etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can use the command `close();` in the button event, thus you'll close the second Screen and return to the first one.